# Use author author display name in permalink structure for pages and posts

Tags: functions, permalinks, users, htaccess, author

I need to add the author name as a subdirectory prefix for all user's posts and pages.

For example:

```
example.com/johndoe/ //The author page for John Doe
example.com/johndoe/category/test-post/ //Test post by user John Doe
example.com/johndoe/test-page/ //Test page by user John Doe
```

If I change the permalink structure to: `/%author%/%category%/%postname%/` this works fine for displaying a user's post but not a user's page.

However I'm not sure if there is something I can do in `.htaccess` or `functions.php` that will allow me to get the `pages` to work in the same manner.

I understand this can be accomplished with Multisite, however I'm trying to avoid using this because the client doesn't want to use it.

Comment: You say "this works fine". So what is wrong ?

Comment: It works fine for posts, but not for pages. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Pages behavior is very different from post behavior... a page url is defined when writing the page (right under page's name). So when you save the page, the url is hard-written in database. Why don't the author simply write posts instead of pages to get this behavior ?

Comment: @Random I have thought about that as last ditch effort, but I was hoping to not have to do it that way.

Comment: From what I see on Google, all you can do is a htaccess rewrite rule... But since the path would be dynamic, it may be hard to write it. So you may have to ask users to use posts instead of pages. Pages are made to be static. You are not supposed to write new pages daily...

Comment: Im backing up @Random. Pages are not supposed to be written daily, that's why posts exist. They have different purposes. **Why?** What about general pages like _contact_ or _about us_? You wouldn't want it be `e.g www.your-site.com/admin/contact`. Avoiding this would require complicated rewrite rules and updating/adding/removing any general page would require checking/updating your rewrite rules. I hope this makes sense. Im not sure what's your business model but it's usually very bad idea to give users access to pages in the first place.

Comment: Well they really wouldn't be written daily. I just want user's to be able to have their own pages such as `example.com/johndoe/about` and `example.com/janesmith/about`.

Comment: Why are you not using `example.com/johndoe`? This is meant to be used for author details. It's `author.php` in theme's root. My question is, how are you planning to solve the issue with generic pages that are made by admin? All those would look like this also: `example.com/admin/blog` or `example.com/admin/contact`. You would need to write exception for each of those pages.

Comment: I am using `example.com/johndoe` for author pages. I was hoping to just use `example.com/page-name` for admin pages and ` `example.com/johndoe/page-name` for user specific pages.

Comment: Pages, as a `post_type` are not really meant for archival use, but rather general utility. Authors are not important on a `page` basis because a page is meant to be collective to the site.

Comment: Will every user have the same set of "pages"?  It would be helpful if you would outline the desired complete solution in more detail, but it seems offhand that you might do better with a programmatic solution involving categories or other taxonomies, or custom post types and custom taxonomies, than by relying on Pages.

Comment: Oops, got snookered by the revived old question syndrome. What I get for StackExchanging on my phone. I'm going to assume this question is dead until further notice...

Comment: With that said: `utility` is for informational purposes and rarely changed, almost static data specific to the "user" or "author" in this case;  `archival` is the data the "user" has input over time.

Comment: @CKMacLeod +1 for custom post type here. Pages post type seem to suck the life out of this CMS faster than Sookie Stackhouse sucks off a vampire.

Comment: Yeah, @NathanPowell, Pages are limited, and then there are a slew of plug-ins and methods for turning them almost into Posts but still calling them Pages, or expanding them with Templates, making them another Custom Post Type under the title "Page," and so on. and so on.That said, the question posed an interesting challenge of the "turn single site into virtual multi-site" genre - which is often, incidentally, a good idea considering the occasional unwieldiness of multi-site (which leads to the other development genre of "turn multi-site" into virtual "single site").

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, there's a plugin to achieve exactly this, so save you rolling your own for it.

The plugin is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/

I installed it to test that it does what you're looking for. Here's a screenshot that shows what you'd do:

[image: Permalinks Customizer]

Answer (score 0):

*Tested with Wordpress 5.0.4*

The first problem to solve it's the *post_name* value for pages that would share the same slug (e.g. *about-me*).

The simpler solution I found is to add the author *nicename* (beware: in my solution it should not contain a hyphen!) as the first part of the slug:

about-me page post_name for john: *john-about-me*
about-me page post_name for mary: *mary-about-me*

This could be achieved using the **wp_insert_post_data** filter hook (see *wp_insert_post()* function defined in *wp-includes/post.php*) when creating the page:

```
// about-me => <author_name>-about-me

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'custom_wp_insert_post_data', 99, 2);

function custom_wp_insert_post_data($data, $postarr)
{
    if(($data["post_type"] == "page") && ($data["post_status"] != "auto-draft"))
    {
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $data["post_author"] );

        // insert
        if($postarr['hidden_post_status'] == "draft") {         
            $data["post_name"] = $author_name . "-" . $data["post_name"];               
        }
        // update
        else {
            list($author, $slug) = explode("-", basename($data["post_name"]), 2 );

            // wrong permalink -> prepend the author
            if($author != $author_name) { 
                $data["post_name"] = $author_name . "-" . $data["post_name"];
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;   
}
```

Next step it will be to change the wp **rewrite rules** to reflect our desires (you need also to update the *settings > permalinks*):

```
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'custom_page_rewrite_rules');

function custom_page_rewrite_rules($page_rewrite) 
{   
    // remove : john/about-me  => index.php?pagename=john/about-me
    unset($page_rewrite["(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$"]);   

    // add: john/about-me  => index.php?pagename=john-about-me
    $page_rewrite["(.?.+?)/(.+?)/?$"] = "index.php?pagename=\$matches[1]-\$matches[2]";

    return $page_rewrite; 
}

add_filter('post_rewrite_rules',  'custom_post_rewrite_rules'); 

// posts have the /%author%/%category%/%postname% permalink structure
function custom_post_rewrite_rules($post_rewrite) 
{   
    // remove: john/about-me  => index.php?category_name=about-me&author_name=john
    unset($post_rewrite["([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$"]);

    return $post_rewrite; 
}
```

Last step it will be to change the value returned when the code asks for a page permalink (e.g. in menus).
To do that we have to use the **page_link** filter hook (located in *get_page_link()* function defined in *wp-includes/link-template.php*)..

```
// http://www.example.com/john-about-me => http://www.example.com/john/about-me
add_filter('page_link', 'custom_page_link', 99, 3);

function custom_page_link( $link, $ID, $sample ) 
{
    list($author, $slug) = explode("-", basename($link), 2 );

    return ( site_url() . "/" . $author . "/" . $slug  );   
}
```

..but it won't work if you don't set to *false* the **use_verbose_page_rules** property of **$wp_rewrite global** instance; this will stop *parse_request()* to check if a "wrong" matched pagepath exixts:

```
add_action('init', 'disable_verbose_page_rule');

function disable_verbose_page_rule()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules = false;            
}
```

That's all.. Well, to be honest this is the main part, but it will be some other work to do, like change the rewrite rules also for all the *attachment/comments/feed/embed* stuff linked to a page and may be something else that I didn't have enough time to discover.

This is my first post; I hope it will help someone, like many others helped me.